# Why dictionary is not like string in urllib post?

Tags: python, dictionary, post, urllib

I am trying to create a dictionary to send data and update the dictionary with the reply. I am creating a communication with an application, sending data using post `(urllib and session)`:

```
ret = s.post(myurl, data=mydata, cookies=mycookie, headers=myhdr)
```

If I send the data using string, communication works fine:

```
mydata = "javax.faces.partial.ajax=true&javax.faces.source=xCreationForm%3AxGroupCtrl&javax.faces.partial.execute=xCreationForm%3AxGroupCtrl&javax.faces.partial.render=xCreationForm%3AxSubgroupCtrl+xCreationForm%3AxCtrl+xCreationForm%3AxGroupCtrl&javax.faces.behavior.event=valueChange&javax.faces.partial.event=change&xCreationForm=xCreationForm&xCreationForm%3AxGroupCtrl_focus=&xCreationForm%3AxGroupCtrl_input=%7B%22id%22%3A1%2C%22name%22%3A%22Node%22%7D&xCreationForm%3AxSubgroupCtrl_focus=&xCreationForm%3AxSubgroupCtrl_input=&xCreationForm%3AxCtrl_focus=&xCreationForm%3AxCtrl_input=&xCreationForm%3AtimeZoneCtrl_focus=&xCreationForm%3AtimeZoneCtrl_input=&xCreationForm%3AxPlanningDate_input=&javax.faces.ViewState=" + faces['javax.faces.ViewState']
```

If I use a dictionary, with the same data, it fails:

```
mydata = {
    'javax.faces.partial.ajax': 'true',
    'javax.faces.source': 'xCreationForm:xGroupCtrl',
    'javax.faces.partial.execute': 'xCreationForm:xGroupCtrl',
    'javax.faces.partial.render': 'xCreationForm:xSubgroupCtrl+xCreationForm:xCtrl+xCreationForm:xGroupCtrl',
    'javax.faces.behavior.event': 'valueChange',
    'javax.faces.partial.event': 'change',
    'xCreationForm': 'xCreationForm',
    'xCreationForm:xGroupCtrl_focus': '',
    'xCreationForm:xGroupCtrl_input': '{"id":1,"name":"Node"}',
    'xCreationForm:xSubgroupCtrl_focus': '',
    'xCreationForm:xSubgroupCtrl_input': '',
    'xCreationForm:xCtrl_focus': '',
    'xCreationForm:xCtrl_input': '',
    'xCreationForm:timeZoneCtrl_focus': '',
    'xCreationForm:timeZoneCtrl_input': '',
    'xCreationForm:xPlanningDate_input': '',
    'javax.faces.ViewState': faces['javax.faces.ViewState']
}
```

Why is this the case? Why does it fail?

Is it because I am using a dictionary-like in the value for `xCreationForm:xGroupCtrl_input`? Special characters?
Do you recommend me use other method to communicate with java-ajax application?

Comment: send to https://httpbin.org/post and it will send you back what it get and you would can compare results for both data.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot [furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas). The problem seems to be the URL encoding. I solved it with https://httpbin.org/post and using `urllib.parse.urlencode(dictionary)`

I included this call in the code and now it works fine. Example:

```
import urllib.parse
mydata = {...}
mydata = urllib.parse.urlencode(mydata)
ret = s.post(myurl, data=mydata, cookies=mycookie, headers=myhdr)
```